# Where should I learn about immersion theory?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology

I'd like to learn the basics of Hirsch-Smale immersion theory.  What sources are best for this?  My background is mostly topological; however, many of the sources I've found on the internet focused on later work of Gromov on the h-principle which seems more analytic than I would like.

Comment: Did you try the book by Eliashberg and Mishachev? You can also read the original papers. 

Comment: In the PL category one can consult Haefliger and Poenaru: "La classification des immersions combinatoires." In the TOP category, Kirby and Siebenmann is a standard reference.

Comment: You can also give a look on Vincent Borelli's page

http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~borrelli/Enseignement.html

But every material is in French!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

M. Weiss has a very good survey on his homepage:
http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/mweis_02/papers.html
called "Immersion theory for homotopy theorists". I also like very much M. Adachi's book "Embeddings and immersions". I think both are very good starters if you have a topological background.

J. Francis has also some notes on his homepage:
http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~jnkf/classes/hprin/
on a course about the h-principle that can be helpful.

Also Eliashberg and Mischachev's book "introduction to the h-principle" is definitively a very good book.

Comment: Remark: I just checked John Francis notes. The crux of the matter, lecture 8, is not available, although most of the notes date from early 2011. Lecture 8 is supposed to have the key step in the proof of Smale-Hirsch theory.

Comment: Weiss' survey has been expanded and published: https://www.gradmath.org/article/immersion-theory-for-homotopy-theorists/

Answer (score 6):

You may like the following lecture notes:

Weiss, M. [*Immersion theory for homotopy theorists*](http://homepages.abdn.ac.uk/m.weiss/preprints/hprin.pdf)

Francis, J. [*The h-principle in topology*](http://math.northwestern.edu/~jnkf/classes/hprin/)

Answer (score 3):

Immersion theory has been "explained" by the Compression Theorem, with new proofs arguably being much more elementary and intuitive:

[Rourke and Sanderson](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301356),

[A master's thesis with another exposition](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/35136)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most readable source:
Haefliger, A.
Lectures on the theorem of Gromov. Proceedings of Liverpool Singularities Symposium, II (1969/1970), pp. 128–141. Lecture Notes in Math., Vol. 209, Springer, Berlin, 1971.